# Socket Hooking / Intercepting / Injecting (Windows)

Tags: windows, sockets, hook, code-injection

I think the title is enough for understanding what I need.
What I want to get is a piece of code that injects 1 packet into another software socket.

My research on this turned some ways to accomplish this

1. I found something about LibPCap, but I don't know if this is able to inject packets too. I know it capture packets.
2. Another way was to use Hook API (inject some DLL's) ... but I didn't understand this, so I haven't managed to use it.
3. Port forwarding was another way

None of this was successful for me because I wasn't focused on any of this one. I want to know witch one is the easiest way to implement and I'll be happy to hear your ideas on doing this.

BEFORE POSTING: I'LL USE THIS JUST TO CHECK OUT SOMETHING ON MY PROJECT. I WON'T USE THIS TO HARM OR HACK.

Comment: Port forwarding has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: Port forwarding to my application and then filter the content received

Comment: port forwarding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) is a technique used when configuring NAT gateways.

Answer (score 1):

If you can go with a little python, [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) should do the trick quite easily :)

Comment: Can you provide me an example on how to sniff and inject ?

Comment: Ok, I sniffed the traffic with WireShark and tried to send a packet. Every thing was OK but the Sequence number. How to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify: wrong number when sniffing? when injecting? what are you doing, exactly? I miss too much info to be able to help you :)

Comment: I started WireShark to sniff all in/out traffic. After I found the Stream/Socket I needed, I made a packet in Scapy p=IP(dst=ip)/TCP(sport=port,dport=port2)/"RAW DATA" and then I sent it with send(p). This doesn't work because the Sequence numbers are not set.

Comment: Have a look to this packet crafting reference (http://www.workrobot.com/sansfire2009/SCAPY-packet-crafting-reference.html), see if it helps :)